# Add count from another table in sql query

Tags: mysql, join

I have created a mysql query using joins In which I am getting the friend list who do chat with each others. This query contains three tables. Now want to add a count from 4th table which contain chatting of users. I have one column name readstatus in that table in which I check if the message is read or not. Now I want to add count of that table in this query but I am not getting correct way add this here is the query

```
SELECT c.c_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_name, u.online_status, c.user_one, c.user_two, u.user_img, c.property_id, p.locality, p.city 
FROM  cpo_conversation c, 
      property_register u,  
      property_for_sale p 
WHERE CASE WHEN c.user_one = '19' THEN c.user_two = u.id 
           WHEN c.user_two = '19' THEN c.user_one = u.id END  
      (c.user_one = '19' OR c.user_two = '19') AND p.id = c.property_id 
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

Comment: please post 4th table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) from ***4th_table*** WHERE ***user_condition*** AND readstatus=1) as your_count, c.c_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, 
u.user_name, u.online_status, c.user_one, c.user_two, u.user_img, 
c.property_id, p.locality, p.city FROM cpo_conversation c, property_register 
u, property_for_sale p WHERE CASE WHEN c.user_one = '19' THEN c.user_two = 
u.id WHEN c.user_two = '19' THEN c.user_one = u.id END (c.user_one = '19' OR 
c.user_two = '19') AND p.id = c.property_id ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

Comment: user condition something like :

4th_table .userid = u.id

Comment: Thanks for  help amit